# opposite of disjoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Sets whose intersection is the empty set are called disjoint. What is the opposite of a disjoint set? For example the sets $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ satisfy this condition. I know that you can just say not-disjoint. But I was wondering if there was a specific term for it. I ask this because someone told me that this term existed but that he could`nt remeber. I have searched extensively but I haven't found it.

Comment: I always say two sets "intersect" or that they "have nonempty intersection".

Comment: "Non-disjoint".

Comment: They are joint!

Comment: Overlapping also works for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be looking for an adjective meaning the opposite of disjoint. Given two sets that aren't disjoint, I would just call them *intersecting sets*, where *intersecting* is an adjectival participle derived from the verb *to intersect*.

Answer (score 13):

If $A\cap B \not= \emptyset$, I say, "$A$ meets $B$."

Comment: I don't just say this, Erdos does:  http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1955-14.pdf (Proof of Theorem 2).  Pontryagin also uses the term in his topology book.  I learned the term from topologists at the University of Texas back in the 80s.  It is a descriptive and useful one.  I do not understand the downvote.

Comment: @Norbert: seriously?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila, Seriously.

Comment: Is there any notation you can use to indicate this? I recall seeing `$A\uparrow B$` but I cannot find it back