# What's an elegant way to express this set relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to express a relationship between sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\neq B$ and $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$. Is there a name for such a relation?

Can assume if needed that both are non empty.

Comment: I just realised your title is not the same as the body of your question. The body simply says that at least one of $A$ or $B$ are non-empty.

Comment: OK, actually, you can just say $A \neq B$. It follows automatically that one of them is nonempty, which is what the second part of your question is saying.

Comment: But that answers the question in the body, not in the title. Maybe you should make them fit, otherwise it's not clear which one you mean.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is that A and B are 'not disjoint', here are some terms people use for this: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168879/opposite-of-disjoint

Comment: The answer to the question in the body of the post is as Dan Shved says in his comment.

Comment: I'm not clear why the title and body mean different things, I'll add another way that may clarify the relationship. If A and B are both non empty sets, what do you name and how do you express when there is x in A\capB and y not in A\capB but y is in A or in B (and not in both). Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If I were writing something and needed to express this, I would write

> Let $A$ and $B$ be distinct sets such that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$.

or even just

> Let $A$ and $B$ be distinct sets with non-empty intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Two sets $A$ and $B$ are **disjoint** if $A\cap B=\varnothing$. The most universally recognized vocabulary that you're looking for is "let $A$ and $B$ be distinct non-disjoint sets."

Comment: hmm,but this does not cover the case where A==B, they are non-disjoint (as A intersection B is non empty == A == B) so, I think its not enough to say it.